# How to properly animate group of mapped items with framer-motion while array is changing?

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I have an array like:
`base = [{title:'foo',items: [1,2]},{title:'bar',items:[1,2,3,4]}]`, then I map through this array with conditions:

```
 <motion.div variants={container} initial="hidden" animate="visible" exit={'hidden'}>
    {base[current].items.map(i =>
     <motion.div key={index} variants={item} >
         <div{i}</div>
     </motion.div>)}
</motion.div>
```

I need to animate all children, but now I only animate that children, which more in array...
for example: (in that case) two children from first array in `base` is visible, if i change array (by toggle with a button for example) children `3` and `4` are appearing with animation, and hiding too, but children `1` and `2` changing without animation, how to resolve it ?

**animation variants:**

```
export const container = {
    hidden: { opacity: 1, scale: 0 },
    visible: {
        opacity: 1,
        scale: 1,
        transition: {
            delayChildren: 0.3,
            staggerChildren: 0.2
        }
    }
};

export const item = {
    hidden: { y: 20, opacity: 0 },
    visible: {
        y: 0,
        opacity: 1
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve it we must to wrap our `motion.div` with `AnimatePresence` with attributes `initial={false} mode={"wait"}`, where mapped items will have different keys: for example `key={i.title}`